# How systemd (v229) feeds hw watchdog

Tags: systemd, watchdog

I enabled hw watchdog in systemd (`RuntimeWatchdogSec=10`) and believe that it was actually enabled:

`# dmesg | grep watchdog
[    3.328676] systemd[1]: Hardware watchdog 'OMAP Watchdog', version 0
[    3.336760] systemd[1]: Set hardware watchdog to 10s.`

Then I wanted to test out if the system really restarts when systemd stops working. As I could not find systemd documentation regarding which systemd daemon feeds the hw watchdog, I tried to kill wildly all systemd daemons one after another (systemd-udevd, systemd-timesyncd, systemd-networkd, systemd-journald, etc) until the console became non function after I killed the systemd daemon (which has a symlink /sbin/init in my system). Until this point, my system still did not restart. Any hints?

Comment: When the systemd daemon is killed, it was automatically restarted (which I also don't know how). I actually removed it so that the restarting failed. But even when systemd couldn't start again, the system still didn't reset.

Answer (score 0):

I've found out that systemd daemon actually opened /dev/watchdog:

`# lsof /dev/watchdog
COMMAND PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
systemd   1 root    4w   CHR 10,130      0t0 6871 /dev/watchdog`

And in my kernel CONFIG_WATCHDOG_NOWAYOUT is not set --> When I killed systemd, no process opened /dev/watchdog and the hardware watchdog was just disabled. When I enabled CONFIG_WATCHDOG_NOWAYOUT, board resets when systemd stops.

Comment: How did you kill systemd? If it’s running as PID 1 it does not die from SIGKILL.

Comment: I did:
# killall init

Comment: Very weird, you shouldn't be able to do that. Killing init causes a kernel panic.